# php and mysql send user to logout on time

Tags: php, mysql

When users login their online status is set to 1 when they logout its set back to 0, im trying to make it so after a certain amount of time of inactivity on the site they will be sent to logout.php, so I setup a field in my users table as last_activity as a timestamp. and have this code as a include on each page.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['last_activity'])) {
    // initiate value
    $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
}
if (time() - $_SESSION['last_activity'] > 500) {
    // last activity is longer then certain amount of time
    header('Location: logout.php');
} else {
    // update last activity timestamp
    $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
}
?>
```

But right now as I have it, the last_activity field only updates when something on the users account is updated, also after the certain amount of time the user isn't logged out and I don't know why.

Comment: Well as i can see your solution is wrong if i go for a tea and come back more than 500 units of time, you redirect me to logout. Try use cron for checking last activity

Comment: anyway, even I support @kirugan. still I have a question, is this your hole checking code. or the previous blocks are inside some functions and you are simplifying your code for the question?

Comment: I just used 500 so it was a quick amount of time ,to test if its working the real amount of time I use will be higher. @mamdouh this is the whole code thats supposed to updated the timestamp check the timestamp and if its been certain amount of time send you to logout.

Comment: ok can you share mysql block of code ?

Comment: anyway, you are not destroying your session. @user1908445

Comment: the session is being destroyed in logout.php thats why I want it redirected tot here because in logout.php its also setting the field online = 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [automatic logout after 15 minutes of inactivity](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?25939-Automatic-Logout-after-15-minutes-of-inactive):

```
<?php
session_start();
$timeout = 10; // Set timeout minutes
$logout_redirect_url = "index.php"; // Set logout URL

$timeout = $timeout * 60; // Converts minutes to seconds
if (isset($_SESSION['start_time'])) {
    $elapsed_time = time() - $_SESSION['start_time'];
    if ($elapsed_time >= $timeout) {
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: $logout_redirect_url");
    }
}
$_SESSION['start_time'] = time();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right just at the top of the file you have to start the session with session_start()